# Thirdweb Contract Not working with react

Tags: ethers.js, react, polygon

My application was working properly but now it is not working properly
made a crowdfunding platform

this is my context file

```
    import React, { useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { useAddress, useContract, useMetamask, useContractWrite } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const { contract } = useContract("0x0Cf484c66E2493875D775Aeea8c426dfAD8d597b")
    const { mutateAsync: createCampaign } = useContractWrite(contract, "createCampaign");

    //line 12: storing the address of current wallet
    const address = useAddress();
    console.log(address);
    const connect = useMetamask();

    const publishCampaign = async (form) => {

        try {
            const data = await createCampaign([
                address, //owner
                form.title,
                form.description,
                form.target,
                new Date(form.deadline).getTime(), //deadline
                form.image,

            ])

            console.log("contract call success", data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("contract call failure", error);
        }


    }

    const getCampaigns = async () => {
        const campaigns = await contract.call("getCampaigns");
        const parsedCampaigns = campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
            owner: campaign.owner,
            title: campaign.title,
            description: campaign.description,
            target: ethers.utils.formatEther(campaign.target.toString()),
            deadline: campaign.deadline.toNumber(),
            amountCollected: ethers.utils.formatEther(campaign.amountCollected.toString()),
            image: campaign.image,
            pId: i
        }));
        return parsedCampaigns;
    }

    const getUserCampaigns = async () => {
        const allCampaigns = await getCampaigns();
        const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter((campaign) => campaign.owner === address);

        return filteredCampaigns;
    }

    const donate = async (pId, amount) => {
        const data = await contract.call("donateToCampaign", pId, { value : ethers.utils.parseEther(amount)});
        return data;
    }

    const getDonations = async (pId) => {
        const donations = await contract.call("getDonators", pId);
        const numberOfDonations = donations[0].length;
        const parsedDonations = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDonations; i++) {
            parsedDonations.push({
                donator: donations[0][i],
                donation: ethers.utils.formatEther(donations[1][i].toString())
            })
        }
        return parsedDonations;
    }

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider
            value={{
                address,
                contract,
                connect,
                createCampaign: publishCampaign,
                getCampaigns,
                getUserCampaigns,
                donate,
                getDonations
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )

}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

this is my main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { ChainId, ThirdwebProvider } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
// import { Sepolia } from "@thirdweb-dev/chains";

import { StateContextProvider } from "./context";

import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
    <ThirdwebProvider desiredChainId={ChainId.Mumbai} activeChain ={ChainId.Mumbai}>
        <Router>
            <StateContextProvider>

                <App />
            </StateContextProvider>
        </Router>
    </ThirdwebProvider>
)
```

error coming is
[image]

contract seems to work fine on thirdweb dashboard